# Write subset of a huge tar file to a new tar file without unpacking first

Tags: subset, archive, tar

I have a huge gzipped tar archive file `huge.tar.gz` from which I want to extract a subset and put it in a new gzipped tar file archive `subset.tar.gz`, without first extracting all of the huge file. For example if listing the content of `huge.tar.gz` :

```
    tar tfz huge.tar.gz
    dir1/bla/bla.bla
    dir2/bla/bla.bla
    dir3/bla/bla.bla
```

, how can I create a new tar archive file `subset.tar.gz` containing only dir1:

```
    tar tfz subset.tar.gz
    dir1/bla/bla.bla
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a two-step process. First you need to extract the directory from the tarball:

```
tar -zxf huge.tar.gz dir1
```

And then you need to compress it:

```
tar -zcf subset.tar.gz dir1
```

Comment: You missed the *without first extracting all of the huge file* bit  ...

Answer (score 1):

The only way I've found of donig this is to delete everything you don't want from the archive (provided you are using a version of tar that supports --delete) you can do the following.

```
gzip -d < huge.tar.gz |tar --delete bla2 bla3 |gzip >part_huge.tar.gz
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be done in one step, without extracting any files, if you have **bsdtar** handy. It supports the `@archive` syntax in place of a file list when creating archives. This tells it to read files from within an existing tarball rather than from the filesystem. If you combine this with `--include` or `--exclude`, you can create a new archive that is a subset of an existing one:

```bash
bsdtar -caf subset.tar.gz --include='dir1/*' @huge.tar.gz
```

You can also use this as a filter in a pipeline with `@-`:

```bash
curl -s https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/coreutils/coreutils-9.1.tar.xz \
    | bsdtar -cJf- --include='coreutils-9.1/doc/*' @- \
    | ssh docserver 'cat > coreutils-docs.tar.xz'
```

bsdtar always tries to detect the compression format of the input archive so there's no need to `zcat` or whatever.

Comment: Nice one! This works but in order to get a proper `tar.gz` file you should call it as `bsdtar zcf`

Comment: @plijnzaad Happily, bsdtar takes care of that automatically with the `-a` switch and `-z` isn't needed. From the manpage: `-a, --auto-compress Use the archive suffix to decide a set of the format and the compressions.`

Comment: @plijnzaad Note that in the second example, when the archive is written to stdout, I use `-J` (for xz compression) rather than `-a`.